# Discord bot does no respond to command

Tags: python, command, discord.py

Recently, I've been making a server specific Discord bot for my friends. When I learned the Discord API can use prefixes and command events rather than the attribute `startswith`, I quickly got started into changing my entire code. I kept the responses of my bot, but changed it to run on `@bot.command`. Despite specifying my preifx and commands, the bot did not respond to me or anyone else on the server. I automatically assumed it was the prefix being an emoji, but changing it to "!" or "$" did not work either. Does anyone know why?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import os
import json
import random
import requests

#welcome channel="852346049959821312"
client = discord.Client()
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members=True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="<:givebanana:852295575772856400>")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    global points
    try:
        with open('data.txt') as f:
            points = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Could not load data.json")
        points = {}

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Welcome",description="Be sure to change your status. Once that is done, you will be assigned the monke intern role. Why don't you say hello to our new monke, <@&852658353678319656>. Viva la monke!", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(0,128,0))
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    channel = client.get_channel(852677413367709706)
    await channel.send(f"{member.mention}", embed=embed)

@bot.command()
async def roles(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Monke Roles",description="The more people DM you 'monke', the more points you earn.", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255,255,53))
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/1/e/9/H/i/banana-md.png")
    embed.add_field(name="Points",value="Someone DMs you and joins the server= 2 points\n\nSomeone DMs you but doesn't join= 1 point\n",inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=" Monke Employee",value="1 Point", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name=" Monke Soldier",value="5 Points",inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name=" Monke Officer",value="10 Points",inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="️ Monke General",value="20 Points",inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name=" Monke Mayor",value="30 Points",inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="️ Monke Govenor",value="50 Points",inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="️ Monke President",value="100 Points",inline=True)
    await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention,embed=embed)
    print('Command Sucessful')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('_**AH AH**_  Here!')

client.run('censoredtoken')
```

Comment: Please be more precise in your demand: What exactly you want to achieve ? What means "nothing happens"? What tests have you made on the code ? What did you try so far ?

Comment: I edited my question, now I'm much more specific with my research and "bug".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the way you declared your bot instance, it should be like this

You are running a client not a bot in your case

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members=True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=intents)


@bot.event
# code 

@bot.command()
# code 

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: I'm a bit closer now, but "bot.run" appears to give me an error? Any more things I should add to my code?

Comment: Error 503, from what I've found in the logs.